# Are Boomeranging Telescopic Phrase Mazes impossible to translate?

Tags: traducción

A Boomeranging Telescopic Phrase Maze is a "fluent" set of words (where one word or phrase leads to the next) that begin and end with the same word. A relatively simple example is:

*I write this in the year 671 * 3 Dog Nights in White Satin Soldier Field of Dreamboat Annie Oakley sunshine on my shoulders of giant reptile roof roof says Bowzerk fitting tang walla-walla Washingtons and what do you get ready or not here I*

Poetry is very difficult to translate (well). Are Boomeranging Telescopic Phrase Mazes "beyond the pale" - impossible to translate?

Comment: The question is about the difficulty of translating, not about spanish itself, therefore is off-topic

Comment: I think "Alice in Wonderland" or "Through the looking glass" have a very good translation in Spain, despite is very difficult to tranlate poems like "Galimatazo" and derivates. Anyway, is there another term to describe the concept you mention? I have searched in google for "Boomeranging Telescopic Phrase Maze" and the only result is this page.... thanks!

Comment: This question would better fit into the scope of the Linguistics site; although I'm not sure how welcome it would be there, either. You might ask on meta (linking back to this question).

Comment: @Arkana: I know of no better term for this genere/style/conceit; Neologist that I am, I coined it myself.